# Local vs. global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to coding and i'm trying to understand the difference between local and global variables. I was trying to create an image gallery where you could switch image by pressing buttons. I got it to work by putting the image variables inside the functions as a local variables. But if i put it outside of the function as one, global variable it wouldn't work. Why is that?

Here is my html:

```
<button onclick="previous_image();"></button>
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image gallery" id="image"/>
<button onclick="next_image();"></button>
```

Here is my Javascript when i got it to work:

```
var image_tracker = "a";

function previous_image(){
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    switch(image_tracker){
        case("a"): 
            image.src = "image3.jpg";
            image_tracker = "c";    
            break;

        case("c"): 
            image.src = "image2.jpg";
            image_tracker = "b";    
            break;

        case("b"): 
            image.src = "image1.jpg";
            image_tracker = "a";    
            break;
    }

}

function next(){
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    switch(image_tracker){
        case("a"): 
            image.src = "image2.jpg";
            image_tracker = "b";    
            break;

        case("b"): 
            image.src = "image3.jpg";
            image_tracker = "c";    
            break;

        case("c"): 
            image.src = "image1.jpg";
            image_tracker = "a";    
            break;
    }

}
```

Here is my javascript when it didn't work:

```
var image_tracker = "a";
var image = document.getElementById("image"); 

function previous_image(){
    switch(image_tracker){
        case("a"): 
            image.src = "image3.jpg";
            image_tracker = "c";    
            break;

        case("c"): 
            image.src = "image2.jpg";
            image_tracker = "b";    
            break;

        case("b"): 
            image.src = "image1.jpg";
            image_tracker = "a";    
            break;
    }

}

function next(){
    switch(image_tracker){
        case("a"): 
            image.src = "image2.jpg";
            image_tracker = "b";    
            break;

        case("b"): 
            image.src = "image3.jpg";
            image_tracker = "c";    
            break;

        case("c"): 
            image.src = "image1.jpg";
            image_tracker = "a";    
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe your elements are not ready when you try to select them? Try `window.onload` function wrapper or put your code to the very end of `<body>`

Comment: `var image = document.getElementById("image");` is executed before the image exists. Inside the function it does because you execute the function after the image object exists in the DOM. You can solve it by doing `var image; window.onload=function() { image = document.getElementById("image"); }` - on another note also add `type="button"` to your buttons. Some browsers would submit the page

Comment: 1- Your document have to be ready to be able to selected elements from the DOM. 2- You have to call your function after defining all used variables in the function.

Comment: just to point out for posterity - this got closed as a duplicate, even though it _wasn't_ (at least to me). this wasn't actually about scope, it was about the DOM not being loaded in time. the scoping issue was just symptomatic of the underlying misunderstanding.

Comment: Ups, i did that by a mistake @strugee . Quite new to this forum. Anyway to get it back to not a duplicate?

Comment: great question! I actually don't know the answer offhand; you should [ask on meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (I already searched for duplicates for you). I'm pretty sure you should have the rep to ask a question, but if you don't I'm happy to ask for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
};
```

Comment: Identical to my comment.

Comment: well, thank you to mplungjan! Didn't know i had to set the type to button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of your second code not working because this line

`var image = document.getElementById("image");`

is running before the DOM is loaded.

If you need to use plain javascript, you may add that line in myFunction

`body onload="myFunction()"`

to load after DOM is loaded.

Comment: No. No need to use inline code.